# Executing ruby code in haml element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here is the haml code that doesn't work as I need

```
%table
-@items.each do |item|
 %tr{:class=>"=cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')"}
```

where `cycle` is a standard Rails method. The output html is

```
 <table>
  <tr class="cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')">
```

What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
%tr{:class=>cycle('list_line_odd', 'list_line_even')}
```

You need to get rid of double quotes so parser would read it like method call rather than string.